# Custom dynamic response with Suave?

Tags: f#, suave

I want to build a simple counter with Suave.

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

  let mutable counter = 0;

  let app =
    choose
      [
        GET
        >=> choose
          [
            path "/" >=> OK "Hello, world. ";
            path "/count" >=> OK (string counter)
          ]
        POST
        >=> choose
          [
            path "/increment"
            >=> (fun context -> async {
              counter <- counter + 1
              return Some context
            })
          ]
      ]

  startWebServer defaultConfig app
  0
```

However, with my current solution, the count at `/count` never updates.

I think this is because the `WebPart` is computed when the app is launched, instead of for each request.

What is the best way to achieve this in Suave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in the assumption that `Webpart`s are values, so computed once. (See [this](https://suave.io/composing.html)).

You need to use a closure to get what you want:

```
path "/count" >=> (fun ctx ->
    async {
        let c = counter in return! OK (string c) ctx
    })
```